# Finding which computer on an unusually configured network is hogging resources

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router

I have a strange network configuration. I want to know if I can diagnose problems with the windows machines at the end of the network.

The setup is like this...

- internet
- public wifi send (comcast/xfinity)
- ubuntu laptop wifi receive (73.x.x.x)
- share over the laptops ethernet (10.42.x.x)
- linksys e1200 router (192.168.1.1)
- three windows machines on a home network (192.168.1.x)

I want to be able to look at something that tells me which of the three machines is using "all" (most) of the traffic when everyone is noticing slowness or connectivity problems.

Can I do this at all with this unusual configuration?

Maybe from the ubuntu laptop? The linksys appears to have nothing useful in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry but as far as I know, the only way you could do something like that is if you re-flash your router with another firmware like [dd-wrt](http://dd-wrt.com/site/index) or [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/).

You can't monitor from the laptop because the router does **NAT** (Network Address Translation) and the only IP the laptop sees is the one configured as *WAN* on the router.

The only way you can monitor from the laptop would be if you used the router as a switch only.

Comment: I've installed dd-wrt. That alone seems to have reduced my need for what I was asking, due to dd-wrt's much improved QoS options. However, I believe I can do what I was asking in a limited way using dd-wrt vlans. They're just a pain to setup and I am not sure I even need them anymore, as mentioned.